# XHTML validating block level element as a link

Tags: xhtml, anchor

I need a way to make an entire DL element clickable with only one anchor tag, that validates as XHTML. As in:

```
<a>
    <dl>
        <dt>Data term</dt>
        <dd>Data definition</dd>
    </dl>
</a>
```

This currently doesn't validate as XHTML as the anchor tag cannot contain the DL. The only way I can get it to validate is if I make two anchor tags and place them inside DT and DD. As in:

```
<dl>
    <dt><a>Data term</a></dt>
    <dd><a>Data definition</a></dt>
</dl>
```

I'm trying to avoid this, as it would result in two href attributes requiring maintenance, introducing the possibility they could become out of sync.

Suggestions?

Comment: also, a non-Javascript solution would be preferable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two years passed but someone may stumble upon this.

New list of solutions:

1. Use non-valid markup
2. Use inner anchors
3. Use JavaScript
4. Use HTML5 doctype instead, it validates nested elements into `<a>` tags

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this and still validate. You will have to make a choice:

1. Use non-valid markup
2. Use inner anchors
3. Use JavaScript

I recommend #2 as it is valid and will work for clients without JS.